# JavaScript 2D array unable to retrieve element in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, multidimensional-array

I have the following JavaScript code that executes fine in Firefox, but in Internet Explorer 9 generates the error message:

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '2': object is null or undefined**

```
var items = [
               [1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [7,8,9],
               [5,5,5],
            ];
    var myString = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        myString += items[i][2];
    }
    alert("Joined number: " + myString);
```

Comment: Remove the last comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE adds a null element after a trailing commas.  Remove the comma after `[5,5,5],`

To explain, `items.length === 4` in FF, but `5` in IE.  The 5th item is `null`, and `null[2]` does not exist.

Comment: D'oh! Talk about not seeing the wood for the trees. I'll mark this correct when it allows me to.